# Hibernate criteria query fetch with embedded id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I have this `Entity` class:

```
@Entity
public class Registered implements Serializable {

    @Id
    public RegisteredId id;
}
```

With this `EmbeddedId`:

```
@Embeddable
public class RegisteredId implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne
    public User user;
    @ManyToOne
    public Tournament tournament;

}
```

I'm trying to make this `Criteria query` fetching the `User` and the `Tournament` because I need to read some of their attributes:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Registered> criteria = builder.createQuery(Registered.class);
Root<Registered> root = criteria.from(Registered.class);
root.fetch("id.user", JoinType.LEFT);
root.fetch("id.tournament", JoinType.LEFT);
criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get("id.tournament.id"), idTournament));
List<Registered> registereds = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Execution exception[[CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [id.user] on this ManagedType
```

What I'm doing wrong?
How can I fetch the relations on an `EmbeddedId` to access them?

Comment: Have you tried to extract variable as `root.alias("id")` and fetch on it? `Selection<Registered> id = root.alias("id"); id.fetch("user", JoinType.LEFT);`?

Answer (score 1):

```
root.fetch("id", JoinType.LEFT).fetch("user", JoinType.LEFT);
root.fetch("id", JoinType.LEFT).fetch("tournament", JoinType.LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
@Embeddable
public class RegisteredId implements Serializable {
    public Long userId;
    public Long tournamentId;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Registered implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    public RegisteredId id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    public User user;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tournamentId", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    public Tournament tournament;
}
```

and then

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Registered> criteria = builder.createQuery(Registered.class);
Root<Registered> root = criteria.from(Registered.class);
root.fetch("user", JoinType.LEFT);
root.fetch("tournament", JoinType.LEFT);
criteria.where(builder.equal(root.get("id.tournamentId"), idTournament));
List<Registered> registereds = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```